# How to restart app after it crashes (or prevent it from even crashing)

Tags: node.js, typescript, typeorm

Noob here :)

**index.ts**

```
AppDataSource.initialize().then(async () => {

    const app = express();

    app.use(express.json());
    app.use(cookieParser());

    app.use(cors({
        credentials: true,
        origin: ["ABOVE YOUR PAYGRADE"]
    }));

    routes(app);

    app.listen(8000, () => {
        console.log('listening to port 8000');
    });

}).catch(error => process.exit());
```

**data-source.ts**

```
export const AppDataSource = new DataSource({
  type: "mysql",

  host: "ABOVE YOUR PAYGRADE",
  username: "ABOVE YOUR PAYGRADE",
  password: "ABOVE YOUR PAYGRADE",
  database: "ABOVE YOUR PAYGRADE",
  
  synchronize: true,
  logging: false,
  migrations: [],
  entities: ["src/entity/*.ts"],
  subscribers: []
});
```

**Question**
How do I force the app to restart after it crashes? At the moment I have to make a change in my code or just press ctrl/cmd + s to restart it. On prod I have to run `pm2 restart appname-here`. I don't want to have to do that if for some reason it crashes (which it only has done once).

Is there code I can add to restart it or prevent it from crashing?

Comment: It is better to prevent your app from crashing. What are the error messages?

Comment: Usually just says it crashed because:
1. data being saved in DB is incorrect; or 
2. something went wrong in the DB;

Comment: Trying to restart your app from inside your app is not always possible. For example out of memory errors are not recoverable at all. You can't run any code if you're out of memory. Stick with PM2 for production and use something like [nodemon](https://www.npmjs.com/package/nodemon) for development

Comment: In that case, if anyone comes across this post and are also using pm2, this should work: ```pm2 start APP_NAME --exp-backoff-restart-delay=100```. I just enabled it now so let's see how it goes :)